# How can I change the font and font size of a gridview as focus/selection changes

Tags: xaml, gridview, uwp

In UWP I'm building a Gridview that contains letters. (e.g. A B C D E F G... Z)  as the user navigates in the Gridview I'd like to change the font(and size) of the currently selected/focused letter.  I'd like to be able to do it via XAML if possible but I can't seem to make it work.

Some background:
I've created a DataTemplate to represent my letters (I have 2 data templates, one for enabled letters and one for disabled letters) and I use an ItemTemplateSelector and databinding to render the list of letters.
I've a LetterModel that represents the Letter and it's state so that At page load some the disabled letters have a different look and those items are disabled in the gridview. I'd now like to be able to change the font and font size via the styling of the LIstViewPresenter (if this is even possible).

Some code:

Letter Model:

```
public class LetterModel
{
    public string Letter { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Data Templates XAML (contained in a resource file along with the GridViewItem Style overrides I've implemented):

```
    <helpers:LetterSelector x:Key="alphabetSelector" EnabledTemplate="{StaticResource LetterEnabled}" DisabledTemplate="{StaticResource LetterEnabled}"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Name="LetterEnabled">
        <TextBlock x:Name="myLetter" Text="{Binding Letter}" Style="{StaticResource LetterTextStyle}" FontSize="24"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Name="LetterDisabled">
        <TextBlock x:Name="myLetter" Text="{Binding Letter}" Style="{StaticResource DisabledLetterTextStyle}" Foreground="{StaticResource MyColor}" FontSize="24"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Declaration of GridView in a page:

```
<GridView x:Name="alphaGrid" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22, 0, 22, 0" 
    SelectionChanged="AlphaGrid_SelectionChanged"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyViewModel.Letters}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource alphabetSelector}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LetterSelectionGridViewStyle}">
```

Here is my LetterSelectionGridViewStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="LetterSelectionGridViewStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,6,6"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-2,-2,-2,-6"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter x:Name="Root" CheckBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCheckBrush}"
                                           ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                           CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCheckBoxBrush}"
                                           ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                           CheckMode="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCheckMode}"
                                           DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                                           DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                                           DragBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemDragBackground}"
                                           DragForeground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemDragForeground}"
                                           FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemFocusBorderBrush}"
                                           FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="{StaticResource MyOrange}"
                                           FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="0,0,0,8"
                                           FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}"
                                           FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}"
                                           HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                           Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                                           PressedBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundPressed}"
                                           PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemPlaceholderBackground}"
                                           PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemForegroundPointerOver}"
                                           PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}"
                                           RevealBorderThickness="{ThemeResource GridViewItemRevealBorderThemeThickness}"
                                           ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                           RevealBorderBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemRevealBorderBrush}"
                                           RevealBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemRevealBackground}"
                                           SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemForegroundSelected}"
                                           SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource GridViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}"
                                           SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlTransparentBrush}"
                                           SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlTransparentBrush}"
                                           SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlTransparentBrush}"
                                           VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </ListViewItemPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Ideally I'd be able to do something in the VisualStateGroups that understands the selected/unselected behavior and I could change the FontSize Properties in my datatemplate

Or am I just misunderstanding something here?

I tried using behaviors in my DataTemplate however that changed all the letter's fonts... not just the selected.

I've spent a lot of time trying to Understand if this should be doable in XAML.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `FontSize=24` in your DataTemplate, then the font size applied to 'ListViewItemPresenter' will not work.

So, if you want to change the font size when the GridViewItem is selected in visual state, you need to remove the `FontSize=24` in your DataTemplate and change the font size in 'Selected' visual state directly.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
     <VisualState.Setters>
          <Setter Target="Root.FontSize" Value="50"></Setter>
     </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: Thank you Xavier!  This is exactly what I was missing.  I moved the font sizes to the selected and normal areas and I now have the behavior I was looking for.